# Use the default Python rather than the Anaconda installation when called from the terminal

Tags: python, linux, anaconda

I recently installed the Anaconda version of Python. Now when I type `python` into the terminal it opens the Anaconda distribution rather than the default distribution. How do I get it to use the default version for the command `python` on Linux ([Ubuntu 12.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29) (Precise Pangolin))?

Comment: Place Python you want to be the default as the first one on the `PATH`?

Comment: in response to Piotr's comment, here is the command: `export PATH="/Users/YOURNAME/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: Can you paste the contents of what the conda init function added for your case? (btw how did you end up solving the problem?)

Comment: For me the conda init does add (to the `.zhrc`) the export command I pasted above but for some reason there is a nested set of if statements that prevent the export from being run. I'm not sure why, but that might be what's happening to you too. Anyway, adding the above after the piece of code that conda init added to my `.zshrc` worked.

Comment: Do you want to use Anaconda or just Python?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Anaconda adds the path to your `.bashrc`, so it is found first. You can add the path to your default Python instance to `.bashrc` or remove the path to Anaconda if you don't want to use it.

You can also use the full path `/usr/bin/python` in Bash to use the default Python interpreter.

If you leave your `.bashrc` file as is, any command you run using `python` will use the Anaconda interpreter. If you want, you could also use an `alias` for each interpreter.

You will see something like `export PATH=$HOME/anaconda/bin:$PATH` in your `.bashrc` file.

So basically, if you want to use Anaconda as your main everyday interpreter, use the full path to your default Python or create an `alias`. If you want it the other way around, remove the `export PATH=...`. from `bashrc` and use full path to Anaconda Python interpreter.

Comment: +1 for the alias idea. In fedora 25, I can add "alias python=/usr/bin/python", and now when I say "python" or "python2" I get the system python 2.7, but if I say "python3" I get the conda python. The advantage of this is that system tools which rely on python 2.7 (like gnome-tweak-tool) work fine.

Comment: What needs to be changed if we have a similar issue in Windows

Comment: Hi, conda added a section rather than a simple line: "# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/dingxin/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/dingxin/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/dingxin/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/dingxin/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<" . how to deal with it in this case?

Comment: Where to find .bashrc in windows?? I want to use python in cmd.

Comment: what is wrong with doing: `export PATH="/Users/YOURNAME/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"`? that seemed to work for me.

Comment: @CharlieParker, It is exactly the same. `$HOME` expands to `/home/user`. It is just shorthand for writing it out and developers are lazy...

Comment: What's annoying is, the conda `pip` also shadows the system `pip`. So if I install dependencies using (conda) `pip` and install another Python binding, which by default use system `Python`, it will fail to work. So for me changing the `PATH` variable  is a better solution.

Comment: I would like to delete Python from `/usr/bin` and use anaconda as default.
coz my IDEA only detecting `/usr/bin/python3` and `/usr/bin/python3.11` as interpreter.
what should I do?

OS: Debian 12

Answer (score 22):

Having tried all the suggestions so far, I think modifying the export statement in file *~/.bashrc*, as Piotr Dobrogost seems to suggest, is the best option considering the following:

- If you remove the whole statement, you have to use full paths for [Conda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conda_(package_manager)) binaries.
- Using Conda 4.4.10 links in the directory *anaconda/bin/* point to binaries in the same directory, not the system ones in */usr/bin*.
- Using this approach you get the system programs for all that have been previously included in $PATH and also the ones specific to anaconda without using full paths.

So in file *~/.bashrc* instead of

```
# Added by the Anaconda3 4.3.0 installer
export PATH="/home/user/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

one would use

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/user/anaconda3/bin"
```

Comment: I also had to change my `~/.bash_profile` in the same way

Comment: This worked for me on MacOS with anaconda installed via `brew cask install anaconda`: `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/anaconda3/bin"`

Comment: This worked. I am curious. Please can you explain why adding the shell command '$PATH'  in front of the path rather than trailing the path prevents conda from being called as the default python interpreter.

Comment: Because in that case the interpreter located in for instance /usr/bin is found before the one in the anaconda directory, and the first match is utilized (check https://www.baeldung.com/linux/path-variable for more details).

Comment: for me the first one you have works. I'm surprised you used the second one. My command: `export PATH="/Users/YOURNAME/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"`

Answer (score 9):

I faced the same issue and you can do the following.

Go into your *[.bashrc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Aliases_and_functions)* file and you will find a similar sort of line:

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

You comment it out and instead type out:

```
alias pyconda='~/anaconda3/bin/python3'
```

Or whatever your path is. This worked out for me.

Answer (score 5):

In the year 2020, Conda adds in a more complicated block of code at the bottom of your `.bash_profile` file that looks something like this:

```sh
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/spacetyper/opt/miniconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/spacetyper/opt/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/spacetyper/opt/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/spacetyper/opt/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

**To use the default Python install by default:** Simply move this section of code to the very top of your `.bash_profile` file.

**To give yourself the option of using the Conda installed Python:** Add this line *below* the Conda code block above.

```sh
alias pyconda="/Users/spacetyper/opt/miniconda3/bin/python3"
```

Now you should be able to call the system Python install with `python` and the Conda install with `pyconda`.

Answer (score 4):

at 2020, like the @spacetyper mentioned, it acted differently. I've found a handy solution for that from this question: [How do I prevent Conda from activating the base environment by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54429210/how-do-i-prevent-conda-from-activating-the-base-environment-by-default)

To disable automatic base activation:

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base false
```

it'll create a `./condarc` in home directory after running the first time.

Answer (score 2):

I found that, though I remove `export=.../anaconda3/bin:$PATH`, there is still `.../anaconda3/envs/py36/bin`(my virtual environment in Anaconda) in `PATH`, and the shell still uses Anaconda Python.

So I `export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH` (`/usr/bin` is where system Python reside). Though there is already `/usr/bin` in`PATH`, we make it searched before the path of Anaconda, and then the shell will use the system Python when you key `python`, `python3.6`, `pip`, `pip3` ....

You can get back to Anaconda by using an alias like mentioned above, or default to Anaconda again by comment `export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH`.

Comment: This does not seem to address the OP question.

Answer (score 1):

There are `python`, `python2` and `python2.7` shortcuts in both the `/home/username/anaconda/bin/` and `/usr/bin/` directory. So you can delete any one of them from one folder and use that for the other.

I mean, if you delete the `python2` shortcut from the Anaconda directory, you will have the Python for Anaconda version and
`python2` for the default version in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I use Anaconda sparingly to build cross-platform packages, but I don't want to use it as my daily driver for Python. For Anaconda, Ruby, and Node.js projects I've adopted to use environment sand-boxing, which essentially hides functionality behind a function away from your path until you specifically need it. I first learned about it from these two GitHub repositories:

*https://github.com/benvan/sandboxd*

*https://github.com/maximbaz/dotfiles*

I have a file of sandboxing functions that looks like this:

#### .zsh/sandboxd.zsh:

```
#!/bin/zsh
# Based on
#    https://github.com/maximbaz/dotfiles/.zsh/sandboxd.zsh
# which was originally adapted from:
#    https://github.vom/benvan/sandboxd

# Start with an empty list of all sandbox cmd:hook pairs
sandbox_hooks=()

# deletes all hooks associated with cmd
function sandbox_delete_hooks() {
    local cmd=$1
    for i in "${sandbox_hooks[@]}";
    do
        if [[ $i == "${cmd}:"* ]]; then
            local hook=$(echo $i | sed "s/.*://")
            unset -f "$hook"
        fi
    done
}

# Prepares the environment and removes hooks
function sandbox() {
    local cmd=$1
    # NOTE: Use original grep, because aliased grep is using color
    if [[ "$(type $cmd | \grep -o function)" = "function" ]]; then
        (>&2 echo "Lazy-loading '$cmd' for the first time...")
        sandbox_delete_hooks $cmd
        sandbox_init_$cmd
    else
        (>&2 echo "sandbox '$cmd' not found.\nIs 'sandbox_init_$cmd() { ... }' defined and 'sandbox_hook $cmd $cmd' called?")
        return 1
    fi
}

function sandbox_hook() {
    local cmd=$1
    local hook=$2

    #echo "Creating hook ($2) for cmd ($1)"
    sandbox_hooks+=("${cmd}:${hook}")

    eval "$hook(){ sandbox $cmd; $hook \$@ }"
}
```

#### .zshrc

In my `.zshrc` I create my sandbox'd function(s):

```
sandbox_hook conda conda
```

This command turns the normal `conda` executable into:

```
conda () {
    sandbox conda
    conda $@
}
```

An added bonus of using this technique is that it speeds up shell loading times because sourcing a number of wrapper scripts (e.g. `nvm`, `rvm`, etc.) can slow your shell startup time.

It also bugged me that Anaconda installed its Python 3 executable as `python` by default, which breaks a lot of legacy Python scripts, but that's a separate issue. Using sandboxing like this makes me explicitly aware that I'm using Anaconda's Python instead of the system default.

Comment: How do I use this?

Comment: I'd recommend looking at the dotfiles I linked to above use it for a good example, but most simply you need to source the sandboxing functions in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`, and then create a sandbox for conda by placing the following _after_ sourcing the sandboxing functions: `sandbox_hook conda conda`

Answer (score 1):

Anaconda 3 adds more than a simple line in my *.bashrc* file.
However, it also backs up the original *.bashrc* file into a *.bashrc-anaconda3.bak* file.

So my solution was to swap the two.

Comment: A .bak file on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

For my case, when I had

```
alias python='/usr/bin/python3.6'
```

in the `~/.bashrc`, it always called `python3.6` inside and outside of Anaconda Virtual Environment.

In this setting, you could set the Python version by `python3` in each Virtual Environment.

Comment: Isn't a VM something else?

Comment: @PeterMortensen You're right. I corrected to Virtual Environment.