# Importing requests into Python using Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-requests

**Preface: I've tried every suggestion in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309288/importerror-no-module-named-requests). None of them work.**

I'm attempting to import the module `requests` into a Python file (using Python 2.7.14).

Visual Studio Code outputted this in the console:

> ImportError: No module named requests

Upon digging, I discovered I don't have `requests` installed, so I fixed that with the following commannd from Terminal:

`sudo pip install requests`, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309288/importerror-no-module-named-requests) with a bazillion upvotes.

I closed VS Code and restarted it, opened my Python file, ran it and I got the same error. I proceeded to try each of the solutions in hopes one would work. None did.

I recently installed `anaconda` and I suspect that is the source of my problem, so I uninstalled every instance of Python I could find via `brew` and also stray installations that were parts of other installations that have accumulated over time on my hard disk based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4).

I then reinstalled python from scratch after running `brew doctor`, `brew prune`, etc.

I also dug into the code settings within Visual Studio Code to see if perhaps that's where my problem was. One of the suggestions was to override the settings for `python` in the `code-runner.executorMap` setting, so I typed `which python` in Terminal to obtain the path to `python` and updated VS Code's User Settings to the path `which python` returned. Now, I'm using this as my `code-runner.executorMap` for `python`:

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "python" : "/usr/bin/python"
}
```

I've verified Python is working by throwing in a couple of simple statements in:

```
print("Printing works fine")
print(1+1)
```

The moment I put `import requests` at the top of the file, I get this error and nothing below it executes:

> [Running] /usr/bin/python "/Users/me/Documents/developerNew/python/tempCodeRunnerFile.py"
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/me/Documents/developerNew/python/tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 1, in 
>       import requests
>   ImportError: No module named requests

I have my file named something else, so I think my problem lives in the "tempCodeRunnnerFile.py". I tried removing the override for the `codeRunner.executorMap`, but that doesn't seem to work either.

I'm out of ideas. If you have one, I welcome your suggestion. Thank you for reading.

Comment: Maybe unrelated to your problem but you should really use use a venv. Apart from that try, `sudo /usr/bin/python -m pip install requests`. pip does not necessarily point to the interpreter you think it does, another option is to specifically use `pip2`. You might also find this useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664435/use-default-python-rather-than-anaconda-installation-when-called-from-the-termin/24664480#24664480

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thank you. I tried that and I get this in console: `/usr/bin/python: No module named pip`. I typed `which pip` in Terminal and it outputs this: `/usr/local/bin/pip`.

Comment: You defo have multiple installs there, this will work `wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py && sudo /usr/bin/python get-pip.py` but unless you have a distinct requirement I would also use `> =py3.6` and definitely use a venv. `which -a python` will also be informative as will `which -a python2` and `which -a python3`

Comment: Thank you! Me RN https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9N0OHdRFcJA Post as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: What os are you running its confusing it seems like ur running or mac or linux but then u mention visual studio code

Comment: @mgracer I'm running a native Mac distribution of VSC. https://code.visualstudio.com/download I'm squared away now. I had an issue that stemmed from multiple versions of Python. Patrick pointed me in the right direction to resolve the issue.

Comment: Oh my bad i was thinking visual studio not code oops

Comment: @Adrian, no worries, I added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is `pip` refers to some interpreter other than `/usr/bin/python`, the quick solution is to *install pip* using `get-pip.py`:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py && sudo /usr/bin/python get-pip.py
```

To debug, `which pip` as you commented outputs:

```
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

So  `pip` is there, it just points to some other interpreter, on my linux box if I check each variation of pip:

```
padraic@dell:~$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
padraic@dell:~$ which pip2
/usr/local/bin/pip2
padraic@dell:~$ which pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
```

We see `/usr/local/bin/pip` refers to my `python3` interpreter.

By far a better option is to use a `venv` and preferably `python3`, `python3.6` has a multitude of huge improvements over all previous releases, to create a `venv`:

```
python -m venv venv
```

It's a while since I used vscode but from memory I think you can use *workspaceRoot* to set the path, I use `venv` consistently as my virtualenv name so something like `"python.pythonPath": "${workspaceRoot}/venv/bin/python"` should work fine.

To install packages for the `venv` you just need to activate:

```
. venv/bin/activate
pip install ....
```

Using *venv's* will save you a lot of headaches in the long run and greatly lessen the chance of screwing up your OS.

Answer (score 10):

VSCode seems to let you import like this,

```
import pip._vendor.requests
```

or

```
from pip._vendor import requests
```

Not sure why this happens. But this happens!

Answer (score 0):

you have one more option you can follow the following steps:

1)Download the package https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f5/4f/280162d4bd4d8aad241a21aecff7a6e46891b905a4341e7ab549ebaf7915/requests-2.23.0.tar.gz

2)Extract it

3)Copy it in the visual studio project folder

4)Include it in the project

5)Import to the Code file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to PowerShell and run command - python
2. See what interpreter you are getting - In my case it is Python 3.11.1
3. Select Python 3.11.1 from view> command palette .

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the python version(s) that are currently on your Windows machine and download it from the Microsoft store.
Tried everything, this was the only one that actually worked.