# Python file pointing to wrong python installation

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, environment-variables

```
F:>where python
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe

F:>PyInstallerFile.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File 
"F:\PyInstallerFile.py", line 13, in <module>
import pandas as pd
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
"Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

I am trying to run my .py file from cmd, my python is installed in

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\

and same has been added to the environment path variables, then why does when I run PyInstallerFile.py file it is pointing to

> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas__init__.py

folder instead of on pointing to ProgramFiles folder.

What am I missing here, what should I do to change this default python location

I could see a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664435/use-default-python-rather-than-anaconda-installation-when-called-from-the-termin) but it was for Linux environment I need to get this solved on Windows.

Comment: You need to install `numpy` as it's a dependency of `pandas`

Comment: Maybe the installation used to run ".py" files is different from installation in PATH, i.e. the result of `where python`. Have you tried running `python PyInstallerFile.py`?

Comment: python PyInstallerFile.py will work but  PyInstallerFile.py is not working as it is pointing to anaconda location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what was the issue though python was added to my environment variables but, uninstalling anaconda and then making python as my primary workspace solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Install lastest version of numpy 1.16.x
In my case Problem resolved with:

```
python3 -m pip unistall numpy
python3 -m pip install numpy==1.14.3
```

Comment: It is not a problem with numpy, its between python installation and Anaconda installation.

Comment: You can also remove anaconda, and define pycharm with interpreter "C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" then it will start working.