# Installing opencv-python on raspberry pi 3, Raspbian Stretch

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, opencv, python

As above, trying to install opencv-python.

Normally this would be a simple `pip install opencv-python`, but it doesn't seem to work. Instead, opencv install to the miniconda directory

```
/home/pi/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

instead of global

```
/usr/lib/python3.7
```

Trying to add `opencv-python` in Thorny through the application fails. In the python program...

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/pi/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages')
import cv2
```

results in a

```
No module named 'cv2.cv2'
```

I've tried adding it to path also (`export PYTHONPATH=/home/pi/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH`) with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Because `pip` is linked to your default Python and I think this default is your miniconda. A better approach is to call the Python version directly with `pip`. Additionally @Dave W. Smit mentioned that you should better install `opencv-python-contrib` to use the full [OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib) package (but don´t use both packages!).

```
$ python-3.7 -m pip install opencv-python-contrib
```

Or you can use the `pip` version (if `pip` is at least version 0.8)

```
$ pip-3.7 install opencv-python-contrib
```

Or with `pip` version 1.5+

```
$ pip3.7 install opencv-python-contrib
```

Comment: That, but I'd install `opencv-python-contrib`, which gets you some extra stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Even with the third point, I get a "ERROR: No matching distribution found". This is a pretty common response everytime I try and install it.

Comment: I got to run to work, but it's possible this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/24664480/5050423 - is the problem

Comment: Please try `sudo apt-get install python-opencv` instead or compile it from [source](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1721668).

Comment: Like I say. Your miniconda is used as the default interpreter and not your Python 3.7.