# When I try to install pandas I receive the error 'no module named pandas', but I do have it installed

Tags: python

I want to install pandas in atom, however when I run
`import pandas as pd`

I get `ImportError: No module named pandas`

I'm confused why because I definitely have pandas downloaded (checked through `pip --freeze`)

when I type python --version I get

`Python 2.7.16 :: Anaconda, Inc.`

Other answers to similar questions have suggested the problem is that pandas is installed on a different version of python. However, when I run

`python2 -m pip install pandas`

I get

```
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in ./opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (0.24.2)
```

if pandas is downloaded to python 2.7 and im running python 2.7, I don't understand why it says it can't be found when trying to install it.

Comment: don't you mean 'import pandas as pd' instead of 'install pandas as pd'

Comment: You can even have two versions of python2.7 installed at different locations.  The python you run seems to come from anaconda, you could try installing pandas there with https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pandas

Generally recommended to use some sort of environment when it comes to python to make sure you know what version (and from where) you are running

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have two different installations of python in your system, one installed via anaconda and another, probably system default.

Try `conda install pandas` instead, since your system is defaulting to the anaconda installation.

Or you could try going back to the default system installation which has [already been covered in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664435/use-default-python-rather-than-anaconda-installation-when-called-from-the-termin).