# How to use the python default interpreter instead of miniconda's base python interpreter

Tags: python, conda, fish, miniconda

My default python interpreter has been set to conda's base environment python interpreter. I would want my default `/usr/bin/python3` to be the default.

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664435/use-the-default-python-rather-than-the-anaconda-installation-when-called-from-th) question which suggests that changing the ordering in PATH would work. However I'm a fish user, so the task becomes a bit more tedious.

Just changing the PATH environment variable using `set -U PATH <my path>` doesn't work probably because of the following section in my `config.fish`

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
if test -f /home/cmaspi/miniconda3/bin/conda
    eval /home/cmaspi/miniconda3/bin/conda "shell.fish" "hook" $argv | source
end
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

Here `conda "shell.fish" "hook"` is probably the culprit that changes PATH, but I'm not sure. How do I change the path such that my good old `/usr/bin/python3` becomes my default?

Comment: You can, in fact, figure out what it does - just run `/home/cmaspi/miniconda3/bin/conda shell.fish hook` without the `source` and it will just print what it would do. (the `eval` looks like useless guff)

Comment: Why not configure Conda not to auto-activate **base**, i.e., `conda config --set auto_activate_base false`? (run once in shell, not in a script)

Comment: @merv the problem is with the path. I had already deactivated base environment but that won't change the path.

Comment: Yes, absolutely it will change PATH - the act of "activating" and "deactivating" environments is fundamentally one of manipulating PATH. If `auto_activate_base: false` is set, then Conda activation code only adds `condabin/` to PATH, which does not include `python` (only the **base** `bin/` does). There is perhaps some confusion about how to configure this properly, and the accepted answer is a very roundabout workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: `fish_add_path` can be told to move a path to the front of $PATH:

```
fish_add_path --path --move /usr/bin
```

("--move" tells it to move already included paths, "--path" tells it to operate on $PATH directly)

This will take care to only leave one /usr/bin in $PATH, and if it already is in front it won't do anything.

If you have a $PATH of

```
/usr/bin /usr/local/bin
```

and conda sets it to

```
/path/to/conda/bin /usr/bin /usr/local/bin
```

this will turn it into

```
/usr/bin /path/to/conda/bin /usr/local/bin
```

You could also store your old $PATH and move all those parts to the front:

```
set -l oldpath $PATH
/home/cmaspi/miniconda3/bin/conda shell.fish hook | source
fish_add_path --move --path $oldpath
```

Or you could move the conda components to the back of $PATH with `--append` (using the actual paths my installation uses):

```
/home/cmaspi/miniconda3/bin/conda shell.fish hook | source
fish_add_path --move --path --append /opt/miniconda3/bin /opt/miniconda3/condabin
```

---

The `conda` invocation here isn't doing anything magic.

It prints code, and `source` then reads that code. You can just inspect it by running `/path/to/conda shell.fish hook`, and see what it prints.

The important bit here is `conda activate base` right at the end. `conda` is a function that the hook defines, and if you follow it you see that `conda activate base` would end up running

```
eval ($CONDA_EXE shell.fish activate base)
```

(where $CONDA_EXE is the path to conda)

This is another command that ends up printing fish code, and you can run it and see that `conda shell.fish activate base` prints, among other things:

```
set -gx PATH "/opt/miniconda3/bin" "/opt/miniconda3/condabin" "/usr/local/sbin" "/usr/local/bin" "/usr/bin" "/usr/bin/site_perl" "/usr/bin/vendor_perl" "/usr/bin/core_perl";
```

where "/opt/miniconda3/bin" and "/opt/miniconda3/condabin" are new and the rest is my old $PATH. So it really just adds these components in front.

Comment: FYI, `condabin/` is simply the interface to expose `conda` - it wouldn't ever have a `python` installed there and shouldn't need moving. Otherwise, I hesitate to endorse this because 1) Conda already provides a mechanism to enable `conda` without masking system software (set `auto_activate_base: false`); 2) it's unclear if this rewriting of the PATH will interfere with Conda's management of PATH in later activations. In some basic testing, it subsequently always inject the environment's `bin/` into the appended position, which would lead to system always dominating.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe add the PATH variable to include "/usr/bin" as the first directory. You can use the `set` command and place this command before the Conda initialization block:

```
# Set the default Python interpreter
set -x PATH /usr/bin $PATH

# >>> conda initialize >>>
if test -f /home/cmaspi/miniconda3/bin/conda
    eval /home/cmaspi/miniconda3/bin/conda "shell.fish" "hook" $argv | source
end
# <<< conda initialize <<<

# Other Fish shell configurations
# ...

# Alias to use 'python' to run Python 3
alias python /usr/bin/python3
```

Remember to `source` the file to apply these changes.

Comment: This has two issues: 1. it adds /usr/bin *before* miniconda prepends its path, so it's ineffectual, 2. it will add /usr/bin every time, duplicating it.

Comment: A simple bandaid is to add /usr/bin *after* running conda.